# How do you capture the screen with accessibility features turned on?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, accessibility

I'm trying to take a screenshot of my screen with Accessibility display features "Invert colors" and "Use grayscale" enabled, but the resulting screenshot images do not have any of the visual modifications. They appear as if the Accessibility features were turned off. Anyone know how to capture this type of image?

Normal: http://3gfp.com/i/normal.png
Inverted & Grayscale: http://3gfp.com/i/inverted-colors_and_grayscale.png

Update: If I capture a movie with QuickTime or ScreenFlow, I get the grayscale effects, but not the inverted colors. Then, I could grab a still from the movie.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the screenshot normally, then open the image in Preview.
2. Press ⌥⌘C to adjust the colour of the image.
3. Drag the saturation slider down to the minimum.

   [image]
4. Swap the colour positions in the histogram.

   [image]

> *Result:*
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks. This is close, but it's not the same. See the pictures I added to the question.

Comment: @Harvey I've updated my result screenshot—not sure I see what the difference is between the accessibility options and this?

Comment: Your image ends up gray, while the one from the options is basically all-black. See the picture I added above.

Comment: @Harvey When I invert colours on my machine, I don't get pure black, I get grey like my screenshot. I presumed the black colour was from the camera that you took the picture with. My invert colours matches the grey; interesting—I'll research this further.

Comment: Are you using 10.10?

Comment: @Harvey Yes; the result screenshot above shows my computer.